# Is this reaction at equilibrium?

Tags: equilibrium

The following equilibrium occurs:

$$\ce{2 NOCl(g) <=> 2 NO(g) + Cl2(g)}$$

A gaseous mixture of $\ce{NOCl}$, $\ce{NO}$ and $\ce{Cl2}$ is put in a container. After a few minutes it is found that two moles of $\ce{NOCl}$ react for every three moles of products which react. Is the mixture at equilibrium? Why? In other words, how does the mole ratio relate to whether or not the reaction is at equilibrium? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information you provided ("two moles of NOCl react for every three moles of products which react") confirms that the reaction occurs as depicted, but is insufficient to establish that the system is at equilibrium. The important missing information is not the relative proportions of these three species in the mixture, but whether those proportions are changing (system is not at equilibrium) or staying the same (system is at equilibrium).

Answer (score 0):

When a chemical system is at equilibrium the rate of the forward reaction equals the rate of the reverse reaction. The equilibrium expression is a ratio of the *conentrations* of the products raised to their stoichiometric coefficients over the concentrations of the reactants raised to their stoichiometric coefficients. So, by knowing the equilibrium constant for the reaction and the concentrations of the species you can tell in what direction the reaction is going to proceed.